# Am I allowed to recommend different code in an answer from what's provided in the question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, code

During answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501027/html-dropdown-menu-options-based-on-previously-selected-option#) another answer was posted and when I studied it, I saw that the user has deleted some lines of code so the code may properly work. Are we allowed to change the given code by the user?

Consider a bug on a big website regarding HTML and JavaScript. The employee has to change some lines of JavaScript code to fix it which he/she cannot find the answer to, so he/she posted the question on Stack Overflow with the HTML. If we are changing the HTML and he/she isn't allowed to do so then what? I know that he/she should provide that information with the question about the restriction.

Leaving the case where the code provided needs improvement or is wrong, then the OP is informed about the change in the code.

If we can work around with the code the OP provided then should we really change it?

Comment: This is [kind of] an interesting circumstance.  The question isn't all that good; it's just asking us to do their coding for them.  No attempt at a solution, just requirements and initial code.  I'd honestly say that it's not worth approaching questions like this at all, and instead voting to close them because of the circumstance you're likely concerned about.

Comment: @Makoto Under what category should we close them?

Comment: "Too Broad" works, since what they're asking for is technically *too* broad (e.g. here's some requirements, here's what I've mocked up, go and write the code for me").

Comment: wow your question is really unclear. So basically is it allowed to make bad answer ? ;) well yes I suppose

Comment: @Stargateur The observations and understanding might be the domain of the error but I think I am quite clear regarding my dispute :)

Answer (score 5):

If by "Am I allowed?" you mean "Is there a site rule that says you're required to use the code in the question?", then yes you are allowed. There is no site rule requiring you to use any of the code in the question.

If you're asking whether it's a good idea:

It can be if changing the existing code helps solve the problem. Future visitors won't necessarily have the same code as the OP anyway.

However, if the code changes are more trouble than it's worth then it could make the answer less useful. Drastic changes not accompanied by an explanation could also make the answer confusing.

In this specific instance, removing menu items that aren't valid based on the selection also solves the OP's problem. It's a different way of getting what the OP wants.

(This is all aside from whether this specific question should be answered at all.)

Comment: Actually it's not the best practice to do so as [hiding the option elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1271583/10967889) won't work for various modern browsers. That's why the disabling solution

Comment: @window.document They aren't hiding the option elements, they're removing them, but I wasn't trying to argue their solution was better than yours. I'll re-word that paragraph so that's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

- This question seems rather obvious to me -- usually users post code to questions *because* it doesn't work. They want to receive some other code that *does* work.
- If your suggestion is "outside the box" we often refer to that as the XY problem and it's encouraged to post answers to questions you think the user "should" have been asking instead.
- Avoid editing questions to make the code work, since that turns the question into a non-question and makes everything confusing. At minimum, don't edit a question to answer the question.

Comment: this has been about editing answers, i didn't realise the questions were in question?

Comment: @ocæon I guess the OP is asking about someone who can change some code but cannot change other code even though the other code may be relevant to change. IDK, maybe try code golf if you like weird restrictions on what you can and can't do.

Answer (score -1):

Editing is at the heart of how these pages become more useful to more users. Looking at answers showing code that has more limitations than the question is not the best case scenario. So where others can see ways to broaden the scope, it's certainly worth *suggesting* an improvement.

Problems can arise however when edits are applied without review. If a user with more than 2000 reputation points spots a potentially useful change, it is applied swiftly and most often works out for the best, but there are still a few hiccups that can occur indirectly. Some cases the original author of the answer still feels some ownership of the post, which is understandable when they are still seeing it's reception in it's original form, but is not how these sites work. Rarely but still significantly, problems arise when the editing user hasn't slowed down enough to explain newly introduced information. Also rarely one may simply forget their edits have become instant, expecting the answer author to understand the edit may not be complete. The messiest situations arise with a combination of these, or when someone *perceives* a combination of these, and even trivial change can take on a life of it's own.

My hope (not directed at any case, and you might not agree it applies in the linked case) is that *when* a concern or confusion arises, people have the opportunity to step back, rollback, and comment. Then without any pressure the situation becomes understandable to those directly involved and passers by (sometimes known as "third user" even though in the presence of edits this is not intuitive) who must take it on faith that all code provided should be in a working state with it's possible scope limits spelled out.

Comment: Please read the question again and thoroughly. This is not what i mean by my question. Not "editing the question" but while answering, editing the code of the user which he/she provided. Editing a question with correct code irrelevant and leads to confusion.

Comment: absolutely agreed, except you seem to read the opposite from my answer, which part led you think i was referring to editing the question?